# Query maximum webcam resolution in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam, resolution

I'm dealing with several types of cameras and I need to know the maximum resolution each one is capable.

Is there a way to query such property in OpenCV?

If not, is there any other way? The application will work under Windows (by the moment) and all the project is being developed using C++.

Comment: I'm refering to cameras supported by OpenCV of course. Cameras such like PGR and others are queried using their own SDKs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A trick that's working for me:

Just set to a very high resolution (above the capabilities of any usual capture device), then get the current resolution.
You will see that the device will automatically switch to his maximum value.

Code example in Python with OpenCV 3.0:

```
HIGH_VALUE = 10000
WIDTH = HIGH_VALUE
HEIGHT = HIGH_VALUE

self.__capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
self.__capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, WIDTH)
self.__capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, HEIGHT)

width = int(self.__capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(self.__capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Worked perfectly, at least with the webcams I have access to. Thanks and sorry for the late answer.

Comment: The order of the width and height setting mattered for me. When I set height followed by width, the resolution is set to 800x640. And when I set width followed by height, the resolution is 1024x768.

Comment: The highest resolution depends on which codec you use. With the camera I'm currently using, the highest resolution reported is 1920x1080. But if I change the codec to MJPG (`cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc(*"MJPG"))`), I get a higher resolution (3840x2160, which is the max resolution of this camera). This information is reported by the `v4l2-ctl` tool, as in the answer of mirella-melo

Answer (score 4):

**FINAL SOLUTION**

As the [accepted answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464688/1485885) by [user2949634](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2949634/user2949634) was written in Python, I'm posting the equivalent implementation in C++ for completeness:

```
void query_maximum_resolution(cv::VideoCapture* camera, int& max_width, int& max_height)
{
  // Save current resolution
  const int current_width  = static_cast<int>(camera->get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH));
  const int current_height = static_cast<int>(camera->get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));

  // Get maximum resolution
  camera->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,  10000);
  camera->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 10000);
  max_width  = static_cast<int>(camera->get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH));
  max_height = static_cast<int>(camera->get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));

  // Restore resolution
  camera->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,  current_width);
  camera->set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, current_height);
}
```

Comment: The order of the width and height setting mattered for me. When I set height followed by width, the resolution is set to 800x640. And when I set width followed by height, the resolution is 1024x768.

Answer (score 2):

Searching on same topic myself : 
As previously answered there is no direct property, but you could find supported resolutions trying to figure out accepted camera resolutions :

1. trying all possible [common resolutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_resolutions)
2. probing minimum resolution and increasing width/height

Here C++ OpenCV 2.4.8/Windows tested code sample

trying common resolutions solution :

```
const CvSize CommonResolutions[] = {
  cvSize(120, 90),
  cvSize(352, 240),
  cvSize(352, 288),
  // and so on
  cvSize(8192, 4608)
};

vector<CvSize> getSupportedResolutions(VideoCapture camera)
{
  vector<CvSize> supportedVideoResolutions;
  int nbTests = sizeof(CommonResolutions) / sizeof(CommonResolutions[0]);

  for (int i = 0; i < nbTests; i++) {
    CvSize test = CommonResolutions[i];

    // try to set resolution
    camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, test.width);
    camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, test.height);

    double width = camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    double height = camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);

    if (test.width == width && test.height == height) {
      supportedVideoResolutions.push_back(test);
    }
  }

  return supportedVideoResolutions;
}
```

Probing solution based on width increment :

```
vector<CvSize> getSupportedResolutionsProbing(VideoCapture camera)
{
    vector<CvSize> supportedVideoResolutions;

    int step = 100;
    double minimumWidth = 16; // Microvision
    double maximumWidth = 1920 + step; // 1080

    CvSize currentSize = cvSize(minimumWidth, 1);
    CvSize previousSize = currentSize;

    while (1) {
        camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, currentSize.width);
        camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, currentSize.height);

        CvSize cameraResolution = cvSize(
            camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),
            camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));


        if (cameraResolution.width == previousSize.width 
                 && cameraResolution.height == previousSize.height)
        {
            supportedVideoResolutions.push_back(cameraResolution);
            currentSize = previousSize = cameraResolution;
        }
        currentSize.width += step;
        if (currentSize.width > maximumWidth)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return supportedVideoResolutions;
}
```

I hope this will be helpful for futur users.

Comment: Long but useful. +1 for the effort put in this.

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu: install

```
sudo apt install v4l-utils
```

And then, run:

```
v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --list-formats-ext
```

Answer (score 1):

[VideoCapture::get(int propId)](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get)

Passing in CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH and CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT will get you the resolution.

For getting the maximum **possible** resolution, all the functionality for `cv::VideoCapture` is in that link. There does not seem to be a possible way to do that directly, probably because many cameras expect you to know the possible resolutions from the manual and to set some flags to toggle what you want. One thing you can try is to keep a list of all common resolutions, then try all of them for each camera with `VideoCapture::set` while checking the return value to see if it was successful. There aren't many resolutions to search, so this should be viable.

Comment: Thank you. This is as far the only way of do it I've also found using OpenCV. Is there another way to determine it? maybe using DShow?

Comment: I'm not sure about DShow, but it seems promising. Also, if you know the protocol, then maybe. For example for IEEE 1394 (firewire), look into [libdc1394 structures](http://damien.douxchamps.net/ieee1394/libdc1394/api/structures/). OpenCV uses it as a backend for IEEE1394 cameras. I would look at DShow first, though, possibly asking another question directed towards DShow users.

Comment: This reports the current resolution, not the max resolution.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of hardware capabilities can be queried from USB devices if the camera is [UVC compliant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_video_device_class). It depends on the driver / firmware of the device. See for example these [Microsoft requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to guess what kind of support you can expect on Windows platforms.